# Error with TensorFlow MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am running OS X El Capitan and python 2.7.10. I installed CPU only version of TensorFlow using pip(following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html)), but when I try to run the [MNIST example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) it gives me an ImportError at

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
```

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import decorators as dec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import SkipTest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Thanks!

Comment: In my case, log out and log in again solved the problem

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/